# Change WebView URL source at runtime

Tags: .net, xaml, maui, maui-windows

I want to change the Source of a .NET MAUI WebView at runtime.

I have this code, which is called by a button in XAML:

**Code behind**

```cs
void OnReloadWebView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
   try
   {
       WebView = new WebView();
       WebView.Source = new UrlWebViewSource
       {
           Url = "https://blog.xamarin.com/"
       };
       WebView.Reload();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

**XAML**

```xml
<StackLayout Margin="10">
    <Button Clicked="OnReloadWebView" Text="Recargar"></Button>
    <ProgressBar Progress ="0.1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="progress"/>
    <WebView x:Name="WebView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
             Navigating="WebView_OnNavigating"
             Navigated="WebView_OnNavigated"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

I was expecting for the WebView to reload and change the URL but nothing happened, not even seems to be reloading.

Comment: Does this even run? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.webview?view=net-maui-7.0) shows that [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.webview.source?view=net-maui-7.0) is a `WebViewSource` object. In WebView's main page the URL is assigned through a `UrlWebViewSource` object

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It does run, and it seems to be the same passing a string URL or this UrlWebViewSource, it is still not reloading to the url I need.

Comment: Have you tried the code shown in the docs? `It does run` may only mean that the exception wasn't observed. `catch (Exception ex){}` hides exceptions. Remove it to see what's going on.  Compilation works because [there's an implicit cast from string to WebViewSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.webviewsource.op_implicit?view=net-maui-7.0#microsoft-maui-controls-webviewsource-op-implicit(system-string)-microsoft-maui-controls-webviewsource). It's unclear whether the string will be treated as a URL or HTML though

Comment: I don't believe there is any need to call `Reload`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's not throwing an exception at all I tried with the sample code you provided and still can't manage to refresh to a difrente URL

Comment: @Jason Even without reload it wont navigate to the desired URL, So I don't really know what to do or if it is even possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should change `x:Name="WebView"` to something like `x:Name="MyWebView"`, because having an object and a class with the same name is confusing:

```xml
<StackLayout Margin="10">
    <Button Clicked="OnReloadWebView" Text="Recargar"></Button>
    <ProgressBar Progress ="0.1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="progress"/>
    <WebView x:Name="MyWebView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             WidthRequest=300
             HeightRequest=300 
             Navigating="WebView_OnNavigating"
             Navigated="WebView_OnNavigated"/>
</StackLayout>
```

You also need to specify a `WidthRequest` and a `HeightRequest` explicitly as per the [official documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?view=net-maui-7.0)

> A WebView must specify its HeightRequest and WidthRequest properties when contained in a HorizontalStackLayout, StackLayout, or VerticalStackLayout. If you fail to specify these properties, the WebView will not render.

Alternatively, you could place the `WebView` inside a `Grid`, then you won't need to request the width and height.

Then, in your code behind you're making the mistake that you're assigning a new `WebView` instance to the field, which you previously also called `WebView` (now changed to `MyWebView`). Instead if doing that, remove the instantiation:

```cs
void OnReloadWebView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
   try
   {
       MyWebView.Source = new UrlWebViewSource
       {
           Url = "https://blog.xamarin.com/"
       };
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

There should also be no need to call `Reload()`, because assigning a new URL should automatically load the new page.

Comment: Nice one! Everything you pointed out was right and solved my issue, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
wv.Source = new UrlWebViewSource() { Url = "http://www.google.com" };
```

Comment: This is true, and it works for me changing the x:Name tag, also solved my problem, thanks for your help!